# MVC Url.Action with glyphicon to call jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following razor on my page:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CopyRequestData", "MyRequests", new { area = "Request", id = itm.RequestID })">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy OptionButton padding-10" id="btnCopyRequest" style="margin-left: 10px;" rowid="@itm.RequestID" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Create a new request based on this one"></span>
</a>
```

I also have this JQuery code:

```
$('#dialog-Copy-request').dialog({
    autoOpen: false, width: 800, resizable: false, modal: true,
    title: "Request",
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function () {
        //CopyRequest();
        return true;
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "No": function () {
        return false;
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

$(document).on('click', '#btnCopyRequest', function () {
    rowid = $(this).attr('rowid');

    $('#dialog-Copy-request').dialog('open');

  });
```

With this the dialog is shown when clicked on the icon button but only for as long as the new view is loaded.
The dialog has two buttons YES and NO.
I would like the new view only to be loaded when YES is clicked.

How can I do this in combination with the a href of the icon button?

Answer (score 1):

You could try blurring the href on click and then setting the location to the href when yes is clicked.

Edited html :

```
<a id="btnCopyRequest" href="@Url.Action("CopyRequestData", "MyRequests", new { area = "Request", id = 1 })">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy OptionButton padding-10" style="margin-left: 10px;" rowid="1" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Create a new request based on this one"></span>
</a>
```

Edited jQuery

```
        $('#dialog-Copy-request').dialog({
            autoOpen: false, width: 800, resizable: false, modal: true,
            title: "Request",
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    window.location.href = $('#btnCopyRequest').attr('href');
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No": function () {
                    return false;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#btnCopyRequest', function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            rowid = $(this).attr('rowid');
            $('#dialog-Copy-request').dialog('open');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of mwwallace8 I figured out how to do this.

```
  $('#dialog-Copy-request').dialog({
    autoOpen: false, width: 600, resizable: false, modal: true,
    title: "Request",
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function () {
        window.location.href = linkObj;
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "No": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#btnCopyRequest', function () {
    rowid = $(this).attr('rowid');
    linkObj = $(this).context.parentNode.href;
    $('#dialog-Copy-request').dialog('open');
    return false;
  });
```

The trick is storing the href link in a global variable and the "return false;" in the click event. Then set window.location.href to the stored link.